# Datediff query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am not a expert in Mongodb so stuck at one point.
I have DTEnd column in my collection where i store end date of an event . I want to fetch closing soon events with criteria sysdate-DTEnd <2 could anybody let me know how to fetch the same in mongodb . Sample schema is as below

```
{ CorporateId: null, CorporateName: 'Nuclues Software', Description: 'Basic AngularJS Training First Semeseter Guys', EndDateTime: Thu Sep 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), NominationCount: 0, StartDateTime: Thu Sep 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Status: null, ViewCount: 22, _id: 52298b8c60df891c30e553ca, Address: { ZipCode: '1212', City: '1212', State: '1212', StreetAddress: '1212', NearestLandMark: '1212' }, Nominations: [], Technologies: [ { Name: 'AngularJS' }, { Name: 'Asp.net' } ] }
```

Solved using $lt and $gte

```
> db.Training.find({EndDateTime:{ $gte: ISODate("2013-09-10T00:00:00.000Z"), $lt
: ISODate("2013-09-12T00:00:00.000Z")}}).count()
```

Comment: can we see an object (json schema) in your collection?

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal Edit your question to include the example doc instead of adding it as a comment so it can be better formatted.

Comment: i solved the problem with $lt and $gte together thanks